# How to get summary basis categorization in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse

I am working with the following structure of Data in R.

Dataframe<-

```
Cust_Id    DateTime             Price    Size     Type    Batch     PI1    Status   Source
TYY-132    2020-08-01 12:14:15  1500     35       RX1     Nov       NA     Done     RDT_DF
TYY-231    2020-08-01 11:04:45  1000     55       Nav     Dpc       NA     WIP      RFF_DF
TYY-131    2020-08-02 10:18:25  1000     25       Nov     Dpc       NA     Done     RFF_DF
TYY-232    2020-08-02 12:14:34  1200     45       RX1     Nvv       GO     Done     RFF_DF
TYY-112    2020-08-03 06:05:01  1300     54       RX1     Nov       GO     Open     RYU_DR
TYY-442    2020-08-03 20:40:50  1500     15       RTR     Nov       NA     Done     RUI_DY
TYY-432    2020-08-03 17:13:12  1000     48       REE     Nvv       NA     Done     RFF_DF
TYY-235    2020-08-04 15:19:11  500      51       RX1     Nov       NA     Done     RFF_DF
```

I want to pivot the above-mentioned dataframe group by `Date` for a particular category.

Category-1: Where, `Size` is >=35 and <=55 with `Type` = RX1 and `Batch` = Nov and value of `PI1` must be `NA` and `Source` must not contain like `RDT_`

Where

- `Count_Order` is the total number of `Cust_Id` for that particular `Date`.
- `Count_Done` is where `Status` is equal to `Done`
- `Total_%` is `Count_Done` divided by `Count_Order`
- `Count_Category1` is those `Cust_Id` for that paricular date which met `Category-1` conditions as mentioned above.
- `Count_Done_Category1` is those `Cust_Id` for that paricular date which met `Category-1` conditions as mentioned above along with `Status` is equal to `Done`.
- `%Category1` is `Count_Done_Category1` divided by `Count_Category1`.

Required Output:

```
Date         Count_Order   Count_Done    Total_%   Count_Category1   Count_Done_Category1  %Category1
2020-08-04   1             1             100.00%   1                 1                     100.00%
2020-08-03   3             2             66.66%    0                 0                     0.00%
2020-08-02   2             2             100.00%   0                 0                     0.00%
2020-08-01   2             2             100.00%   0                 0                     0.00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way with `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(category1 = between(Size, 35, 55) & Type == 'RX1' & 
           Batch == 'Nov' & is.na(PI1) & !grepl('RDT_', Source)) %>%
  group_by(Date = as.Date(DateTime)) %>%
  summarise(Count_Order = n(), 
            Count_Done = sum(Status == 'Done'), 
            `Total_%` = Count_Done/Count_Order * 100, 
            Count_Category1 = sum(category1),
            Count_Done_Category1 = sum(category1 & Status == 'Done'),
            `%Category1` = Count_Done_Category1/Count_Category1 * 100) %>%
  replace(is.na(.), 0)

#   Date       Count_Order Count_Done `Total_%` Count_Category1 Count_Done_Catego… `%Category1`
#  <date>           <int>      <int>     <dbl>           <int>              <int>        <dbl>
#1 2020-08-01           2          1      50                 0                  0            0
#2 2020-08-02           2          2     100                 0                  0            0
#3 2020-08-03           3          2      66.7               0                  0            0
#4 2020-08-04           1          1     100                 1                  1          100
```

Comment: I want to remove `between(Size, 35, 55)`, can  I remove it direclty?

Comment: Yes, you can remove it by `df %>% filter(!between(Size, 35, 55))`

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to include `between(Size, 35, 55)` condition for `category1` ?  In that case, yes you can use what you have suggested in the above comment.

Comment: If you want to exclude you can use `!grepl('RDT_', Source)`. Updated the answer.

Comment: You can keep whichever condition you want in `category1` and remove the ones which you don't want. `df %>% mutate(category1 = Type == 'RX1' & is.na(PI1)) %>% ....`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. It is better to ask that as a new question instead of extending the question in comments. I think I answered your original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227482/discussion-between-user9211845-and-ronak-shah).